# How do I look for strings in a list that are non blank or non empty in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that contain empty strings, blank strings and strings with words in it, how do I explicitly count the number of empty and blank strings?

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['', ' ', 'abc']
sum(not s.strip() for s in l)
```

Comment: The solution is indeed nice, but it is sure to puzzle a beginner. The very idea that `sum([True, True, False]) == 2` takes digging pretty deep in Python's historical guts.

Answer (score 0):

just try a loop with strip

```
list_str ...

for str_temp in list_str[:]: # must use [:] to copy a list
    if ('' == str_temp.strip()):
        list_str.remove(str_temp)
```

Comment: A piece of (unsolicited) advice: if you can, do not modify input data. For instance, the caller might have other plans for that data.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
input_data = ["foo", " ", "bar", ""]

def isEmptyOrBlank(s):
  return ... # come up with something, do your homework

target_strings = [s for s in input_data if isEmptyOrBlank(s)]

the_answer = len(target_strings)
```

There can be a few more succinct solutions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of string called stringList, I would do:

For empty strings:

```
count = len([item for item in stringList if item ==''])
```

For instances of None:

```
count = len([item for item in stringList if item is None])
```

For a combined count:

```
count = len([item for item in stringList if not item])
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of elements in your list are strings:

```
your_list = ['', '   ', 'aasd', 'asd', 'xc', ' ', '\n', '44']
result = len([x for x in a if not x.isalnum()])
print result
4
```

**Edited**: `.isalnum()` instead of `.isalpha()`

Comment: What if `your_list = [" ", "", "C3PO", "R2D2"]`?

Comment: You're right, I typed wrong method, thanks. Check edit.

Comment: I like your style, but beware of ``["Ok.", "Nice!", "Soufflé"]``

Comment: Instead of trying to detect all classes of characters that are not blank, you could detect a narrower class of whitespace and invert the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Get the sum of the elements that are not equal to either:

```
print(sum(s not in {""," "} for s in l))
```

Or for arbitrary amounts of space, use str.isspace:

```
print(sum(s != "" and not s.isspace() for s in l))
```